# How to use filters in Terraformer for importing google compute address?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have a google compute address named cloud-instance. I am using https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer to import it.

I am unable to use filters and generate the terraform files for a google compute address.
I have tried the following till now but all of them either selects all the addresses & generates the .tf files for them or selects no address at all.

```
terraformer import google --resources=addresses --filter Name=name;Value=cloud-instance --connect=true --regions=europe-west3 --projects=<project_id>
```

filters and imports one required address.

But I want something like this

```
terraformer import google --resources=addresses,gke --filter Type=addresses;Name=name;Value=cloud-instance --connect=true --regions=europe-west3 --projects=<product_id>
```

So that it imports my k8s cluster and only one address whose name is cloud-instance. But this is not working.

Can someone help me to use this right way?